# Hibernate persist entity, but ignore it's associated child entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using Hibernate:6.2.2 + SpringBoot:3.1.0 + java17 + postgresql

```java
@Entity
public class AccountEntity{

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)
    private CardTypeEntity cardTypeEntity;
}

@Entity
public class CardTypeEntity{
    @Id
    private Short id;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_TYPENAME_NAME, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String typeName;
}
```

Table account have a column **type_id** linked to table card_type's pk **id**, and card_type has a not-null and unique column type_name.

- i wanna save new record of account into database

  - when typeName exists in card_type, only insert account with existing card_type's id link to type_id
  - when typeName not exist, insert both account and card_type
  - **how can i archive this?**
- spring `CrudRepository.save(accountEntity)` and `entityManager.persist(accountEntity)` both may cause duplicate exception if type_name exists